# How to print base64 string which contains a table using crystal report

Tags: html, crystal-reports

I am printing base64 string in crystal report. When my base64 string contains normal plain data it is getting printed but if my **base64 string has data in tabular format** then data from the table is getting displayed plainly not in tabular format. **Only text is getting printed not table**.
So how to print data with table or in tabular format?
My code is as follows

```
 const win = window.open("", "_blank");
  let html = "";
  html += "<html>";
  html += '<body style="margin:0!important">';
  html += '<embed width="100%" height="100%" src="data:application/pdf;base64,' + result + '" type="application/pdf" />';
  html += "</body>";
  html += "</html>";
  win.document.write(html);
```

In above code, **result contains data to be displayed**.(data contains table).
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal doesn't support table layout as html tags. But you can get around that limitation by using a Crystal Reports UFL (User Function Library) that, on the fly, converts the HTML to an image and returns the path to the image for display in the report.

You can create the UFL or use an existing 3rd-party UFL. At least one of the 3rd-party UFLs listed [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#ufl) provides this functionality. For example:

[image]